# Whether each word in a sentence is 'valid' - python

Tags: python

I am trying to create a code where the user enters a sentence and the computer tells them if each word in the sentence is 'valid' (so in terms of python, if each of the words in their sentence is in the 'validwords' list.)

```
sentence = input("Please enter a sentence: ")
validwords = ["hello","i","like","python"]
word = sentence.split(" ")
for word in sentence:
      if word in validwords:
           print ("I found a valid word: "+str(word))
      else:
           print ("I found an invalid word: "+str(word))
```

however, the final five lines do not seem to work as they split up each letter in the sentence instead of each word.

Comment: `word = sentence.split(" ")`... You didn't loop over these, you looped over the `sentence` characters

Comment: You split the sentence into a list and name it `word` but then you never use it: `word = sentence.split(" ")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looping over the characters in the original sentence instead of the list of words you created. Try this:

```
sentence = input("Please enter a sentence: ")
validwords = ["hello","i","like","python"]
words = sentence.split(" ")
for word in words:
      if word in validwords:
           print ("I found a valid word: " + word)
      else:
           print ("I found an invalid word: " + word)
```

Answer (score 1):

You have your loop variables mixed up. I suggest

```
validwords = set(validwords) # use a set for faster lookup times
words = sentence.split() # split by all whitespace
for word in words:
    # check whether word in validwords
```

In case you are looking for a shorthand to check if all typed words are valid, you can use:

```
validwords = set(validwords) # use a set for faster lookup times
success = all(word in validwords for word in sentence.split())
```

Of course, this does not allow for intermediary printing.

Answer (score 0):

> the final five lines ... split up each letter in the sentence

That would be the for-loop. Strings are iterable by characters. You looped over the input string, not the split value.

Try

```
for word in sentence.split(" "):
```